# Adding new Capability on runtime to appium driver after its being instanciated

Tags: appium, appium-ios, remotewebdriver

is it possible to add new capability to Appium driver (Android &/IOSdriver) after driver's being instantiated?
Or are there set of capabilities that could be added

Also, is it possible to achieve the same for Selenium's remotewebdriver.
Thanks

Comment: what capability do you want to add ?

Comment: I am interested in setting-up "autoWebview" capability but also would like to know what other capabilities we can set / change on runtime. Thanks

Comment: why you want to that capability ?

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible. You can get capabilities during run time but if you want to change them you need new WebDriver session.